# Problems with proof-at-the-end package

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I am recently using the proof-at-the-end package, which is supposed to move all proofs in some chosen appendix of your paper. Although I find this quite useful, I am experiencing difficulties for which I have been unable to find any answer.

I use standard AMS packages on TeXLive 2020 and added the line

```
\usepackage[conf={proof at the end, no link to proof, one big link}]{proof-at-the-end}
```

to my preamble.

1. the text of the statements and of the proofs written with the {theoremEnd} environment do no longer permit synchronization between source and pdf;
2. one precise theorem causes an error which prevents compiling the file returning message
   "! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'rhoad' will be lost."

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please, show a complete (but short) example of code.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclamer:** I wrote this library.

Concerning the issues with the synchronization between the source and the pdf, this is due to the way the library works: when it finds a text to move in the appendix, it will append it in a separate file (you can see them, they are named like `pratendNameOfCategory.tex`), and then the code just inputs this file. Therefore, when you want to synchronize the pdf and the source, you will be redirected to this temporary file instead of inside the main pdf. I have no idea if there is a way to help synctex to find the actual code (I would love to try to implement that), and I'm also not aware of a much better way to design the library to avoid that issue. In case anybody has a solution for that, I would be happy to try to implement it. But other libraries like `comment` also suffer from the same bug, so I guess it is hard to avoid.

The workaround I usually use is the following: when I write the proof or make many changes in a proof, I use a style like `debug` to ensure that the proof is also written in the main text: the link pdf-tex will work there. Once the proof is finished, I move the proof in the appendix, and if I find a typo, I click on the link that points to the theorem: it brings me back to the main paper in which I can use again the link pdf-tex. You may also find search (`C-s` in emacs) practical to quickly find your text in your file.

Concerning your second problem, I've no idea. I never encountered this kind of bug. A complete minimal working example would help. Also, feel free to fill issues [here](https://github.com/leo-colisson/proof-at-the-end/issues).